# python: split string without discarding anything

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I'd like to do something like this:

```
import re
s = 'This is a test'
re.split('(?<= )', s)
```

add get back something like this:

```
['This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'test']
```

but that doesn't work.

Can anybody suggest a simple way to split a string based on a regular expression (my actual code is more complicated and does require a regex) without discarding any content?

Comment: Something like `[i for i in re.split('([^ ]+ ?)',s) if i]`?

Comment: @fredtantini you should add that as an answer

Comment: @fredtantini Amazing!  and I used to say that Perl was the APL of the 21th century...

Comment: @fredtantini Putting a regex in parens seems to change the behavior of `re.split`.  Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @BrentBaccala quoting https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split `If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `re.findall`?

```
re.findall(r"(\w+\s*)", s)
```

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of **re.split()** is to define a delimiter to split by. While you will find other answers that can actually make your case work, I sense that you would be happier with something like **re.findall()**

```
re.findall(r'(\S+\s*)', s)
```

gives you

```
['This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'test']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` module here.

```
import regex
s = 'This is a test'
print regex.split('(?<= )', s,flags=regex.VERSION1)
```

Output:

`['This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'test']`

or

```
import re
s = 'This is a test'
print [i for i in re.split(r'(\w+\s+)', s,) if i]
```

Note: `0 width assertions are not supported in re module for split`

Answer (score 1):

Capture the delimiter and then rejoin the delimiter to the previous word:

```
>>> it = iter(re.split('( )', s)+[''])
>>> [word+delimiter for word, delimiter in zip(it, it)]
['This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'test']
```

Answer (score 0):

at least on alphabetic characters and one space for split :

```
[i for i in re.split('(\w+ +)',s) if i] # ['This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'test']
```